# iOS: app freezes when dictionary key contains a period?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

The simplified code below freezes when dictionary keys contain a period. The app doesn't crash, just ignores gestures and touches. For instance, the `touchesBegan` function in the UIViewController doesn't get called.

Replacing the period with another character like a dash allows the app to function.

Are Swift dictionaries not allowed to contain periods in keys?

```
let name = "TSC-Body.043" // App fails with this "name" definition
// let name = "TSC-Body-043" // App works with this "name" definition

var test = [String:Any]()
if test[name] == nil {
    test[name] = UIColor.black
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Never gets called with a period in keys")
}
```

Comment: tested your code did not freeze the app you sure this statement is causing the issue ? Pause the execution when app freezes and check where is current execution pointer pointing at

Comment: A period can be treated as key path separator in some cases. But just getting a value from a dictionary a key including a period should work.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari it doesn't stop execution, it continues past that point but just ignores touches and gestures. using dashes instead of periods makes the app work. does your app respond to `touchesBegan` with the period in the key?

Comment: @crashalot : I havent particularly tested touchesBegan method but I had UISlider on my view which I could freely drag around n a couple of button which are tappable and working fine no lag in UI nothing is blocking my MainThread

Comment: Just tested it with touchesBegan, did not reproduced (tested on simulator)